# -webkit-transform does not work in Android webview

Tags: android, css, webview, webkit, rotation

i have applied the following css to an image in span tag.

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
transform:rotate(-2deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
```

this css style works on ios webview, desktop browser, but not on android webview, which is also webkit based.

my question is why this is not rendered on Android.

Comment: I know it's 4 years ago, but did you ever get this problem solved? Trying to transform an image (not even rotate) and it doesn't work on Android webview, but works everywhere else, including the webview in the emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am using android version 3.1 and this code working fine for me..
my code is below

```
.transofmr
{
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
transform: rotate(30deg);

width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#339933;
}
<div class="transofmr">Transform</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the rotation transform is only applied to block level elements.  A span is an inlined element by default.

Comment: This is a fairly old question with an accepted answer. It would be good if you could backup your assertions with references to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

this will help u.. i have checked this in Motorlla XOOM device..

```
.transofmr
{
transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: thanks cgvector.  i am not sure if this is phone hardware related. i tried galaxy s2 and motorola droid, both are not rotating. but i tried  in simulator, everything is working as expected.  do u think this has to do with version of the android phone? rendering engine of browser of yours? if so can you tell me the version of ur xoom so i can check mine as well?